# проблемы с конфигурацией логгера, java

Tags: java

У меня есть файл конфига для логгера log4j.xml, но когда я пытаюсь его подключить для инициализации логгера, почему то он его ищет не в папке проекта корневой, а ищет на рабочем столе, подскажите что может быть не так?

```
static {
    new DOMConfigurator().doConfigure("log4j.xml", LogManager.getLoggerRepository());
}

static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ServletController.class);
```

Comment: как вы запускаете этот код? почему думаете, что ищет на рабочем столе?

Answer (score 0):

1. Конфигурация log4j2.xml должна лежать в ресурсах проекта. Этого достаточно для того, чтобы при запуске приложения логгер был проинициализирован.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Если нужно на горячую перезагрузить конфигурацию логгера.
   Код ниже вычитывает конфигурацию из ресурсов, но по аналогии можно сделать и по нужному пути:

   ```
   import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
   import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
   import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;
   import org.slf4j.Logger;
   import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.FileOutputStream;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStream;

   public class Log {

       static {
           System.setProperty("java.util.logging.manager", "org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager");
       }

       private static final Logger console  = LoggerFactory.getLogger("Console");

       private static final Logger framework = LoggerFactory.getLogger("Framework");

       public static Logger console() {
           return console;
       }

       public static Logger framework() {
           return framework;
       }

       public static synchronized void forceReloadConfig() {
           LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
           String file = "log4j2.xml";
           try (InputStream inputStream = TestUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(file)) {
               final File tempFile = File.createTempFile(file, ".tmp");
               try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile)) {
                   IOUtils.copy(inputStream, out);
               }
               // Принудительная перезагрузки конфигурации.
               context.setConfigLocation(tempFile.toURI());
               framework.debug("Логгер инициализирован .");
           } catch (IOException e) {
               framework.error("Ошибка перезагрузки конфигурации log4j", e);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Пример log4j2.xml с цветовой дифференциацией консольных логов.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Configuration>
       <properties>
           <!-- Корневой путь к директории логов. Инициализируется 1 раз при запуске. -->
           <!-- вычитывается системная переменная System.setProperty("LOG_DIR", logPath); -->
           <property name="log.path">${sys:LOG_DIR}</property>
           <property name="log.pattern">%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5p] [%25.25C] - %m%n</property>
           <property name="colors">{FATAL=red blink, ERROR=red, WARN=Magenta, INFO=black, DEBUG=green, TRACE=blue}</property>
           <property name="rb">red bright</property>
           <property name="bex">{FATAL=${rb}, ERROR=${rb}, WARN=${rb}, INFO=${rb}, DEBUG=${rb}, TRACE=${rb}}</property>
       </properties>
       <Appenders>
           <Console name="SlowConsole" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
               <PatternLayout pattern="%highlight{[%-5p] %msg%n}${colors}%highlight{%ex}${bex}"/>
           </Console>
           <File name="Framework" fileName="${log.path}/Framework.log">
               <PatternLayout pattern="${log.pattern}"/>
           </File>
       </Appenders>
       <Loggers>
           <Logger name= "Console" level="all" additivity="false">
               <AppenderRef ref="SlowConsole" level="TRACE"/>
           </Logger>
           <Logger name="Framework" level="info" additivity="false">
               <AppenderRef ref="Framework" level="TRACE"/>
           </Logger>
       </Loggers>
   </Configuration>
   ```
4. pom.xml

   ```
   <properties>
       <log4j.version>2.8.2</log4j.version>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
           <version>${log4j.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
           <version>${log4j.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>log4j-jul</artifactId>
           <version>${log4j.version}</version>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   ```

Этого достаточно для решения проблемы.